# Flowplayer local videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

Is there a way to pull in videos from the users local pc.

So for example the website will be hosted externall www.example.com - but the pc's that will be accessing the site we want the videos to run locally. I'm currently trying:

```
flowplayer("player", {src: 'file://C:/videos/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', wmode: 'opaque'}, { plugins: { controls: { autoHide: 'always', 
       // which buttons are visible and which are not?
        play:false,
        volume:true,
        mute:true,
        time:false,
        stop:false,
        playlist:false,
        fullscreen:true,
        // scrubber is a well-known nickname for the timeline/playhead combination
        scrubber: false
}}, clip:{ autoPlay: true, autoBuffering: true }, canvas: {backgroundColor: '#7790ac'}});
```

But unfortunatley - not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've ended up installing IIS on the local pcs and calling a http://localhost url.